# cannot create folder using google drive api in python, error just says Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: python

```
import pickle
import os.path
import win32api
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from datetime import date

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

today = date.today()
# current date
d1 = today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """

    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    # if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        #with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            #creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.


    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",spaces="drive",
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()\

    items = results.get('files', [])
    file_metadata = {
        'name': d1,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        }
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()



    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:       #start things here hehe
        print(items)
        print("d1 =", d1)
        print ('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Yes i tried to delete the pickle file and run the app again, no commenting out the creation of the pickle file didnt help. when i run the python file it runs for like 30 secs with no response followed by a shiton of random errors that end in the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

after a day and restarting my pc and trying to delete the pickle file (again) it kinda just worked